# Get value from graphicView.bidvalue

Tags: python, css, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the value of 5,2329 from this code using Beautiful Soup in python. What should I do to properly do it?

```
<span class="chart-info-val ng-binding" ng-bind="graphicView.bidvalue">5,2329</span>
```

My code is:

```
    def info(link):
    html = urlopen(link)
    res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
    main = res.findAll("div",{"class":"info-content"})
    tag = main[0]
    cotacao = tag.select('span.chart-info-val ng-binding')
    print(cotacao)


info("https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/acoes/bvsp-bovespa/wege3-sa")
```

Ps: <span is inside the div

Comment: Looks like your code didn't come through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code, so I can only assume certain things.

### Code Example

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.select('span.chart-info-val ng-binding').get_text()
```

### Explanation

The select method uses CSS selectors to grab the HTML that has been parsed by beautifulsoup.

```
soup.select('span.chart-info-val ng-binding').get_text()
```

The example above

- `span`: grabs any span tag
- `.` : signifies a class in CSS here the class is chart-info-val ng-binding
- `get_text()`: Grabs the text from the span with class chart-info-val ng-binding

After finding out the URL I know understand why you've not be able to grab the content. As I explained, the browser loads information in three main ways. HTML,CSS and Javascript. HTML is strictly for text and marking up the page, CSS for styling and Javascript can do allsorts, including generating data. Here everytime you refresh the page, the website is making a server call to grab the data of the stock price and then display it. It's not hardcoded into the HTML, the javascript is embedding it.

BeautifulSoup can't handle javascript generated websites without some help.

### Additional Information

Generally speaking there are three ways to grab data dynamically.

1. Reverse engineering the HTTP requests.

That is because javascript is making calls to the server, if we can mimic those requests can should be able to obtain the data we want. The advantage of this approach is that it's fast and efficient. Unlike other approaches. This can often require to just making a simple HTTP get/post request, but also may need to add things like headers, cookies and parameters.

2. Pre-render the page using splash

The Splash framework can prerender the page, that is capture the document DOM and allow you to be able to select all of it. It isn't as efficient as reverse engineering the HTTP requests but it's relatively lightweight approach

3. Rendering the page and using browser activity.

You can the selenium package to mimic browser activity, fool the website you're using a browser. It's heavyweight and the framework was never really meant for webscraping but used for automated testing. Essentially the selenium webdriver provides an HTTP server, a secure connection with a browser. We can then do any browser activity by sending HTTP requests to this server and direct the webdriver to a special type of browser for automated testing. This becomes a slow approach depending on your data needs.

### Code Update

With that being said, the website you want data from is actually quite easy to obtain the information you want. We can do this by reverse engineering HTTP requests. Essentially the website is making a HTTP get request a server and then the response displays the stock price.

To Understand how the website is doing this we have to be able to inspect the requests. Using chrometools this is quite easy. If you load the page, right click inspect you will get a window up with the HTML code. If you click network tabs you can see a list of all the requests.

Here is some images to guide you through looking through the HTTP requests. We essentially are recording browser activity. In the XHR that is XMLHttpRequest which refers to the requests javascript generates to grab data, this is where data can be found. We click through the requests and click preview till we see the data we want from the request. We then right click and copy the CURL BASH command and paste it into a website like curl.trillworks.com. Here we can convert the request into python. Which gives us nice formated headers/params/cookies to make the request look genuine.

Images:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TRtL.jpg)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGd0K.jpg)

So now we have the correct URL to make the request, plus any headers. Firstly it's worth trying an requests get method on just the server. If you're lucky you don't need to include headers/params. Testing this out, the only thing you need to do is use the parameters and make a get request, no need for headers.
Here are the HTTP request details.

```
url = 'https://api.cotacoes.uol.com/asset/intraday/list/'
params = (('format', 'JSON'),
         ('fields', 'price,high,low,open,volume,close,bid,ask,change,pctChange,date'),
         ('item', '704'),
         ('', ''),)
headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Referer': 'https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/acoes/bvsp-bovespa/wege3-sa',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',}
```

With that, you can do abit of testing with the code below. It turns out you don't need those headers and it just requires the parameters.

### Coding Examples

```
import requests 

params = (
('format', 'JSON'),
('fields', 'price,high,low,open,volume,close,bid,ask,change,pctChange,date'),
('item', '704'),
('', ''),)

response = requests.get('https://api.cotacoes.uol.com/asset/intraday/list/', params=params)

 data = response.json()
```

#### Output

```
{'prev': None,
 'next': None,
 'docs': [{'price': 58.09,
   'high': 58.46,
   'low': 54.7,
   'open': 55.03,
   'volume': 6435500,
   'close': 54.55,
   'bid': 58.09,
   'ask': 58.11,
   'change': 3.54,
   'pctChange': 6.49,
```

### Explanation

Here we've taken the parameters from curl.trillworks.com and using the URL we located in the images we're making a get request with those specific parameters.  The response we get back is called a JSON object. The response.json() method converts this JSON object into a python dictionary which can be manipulated. Here you can see the output with the desired data.

To get the data you want we have go through this dictionary. You can see the desired data is in the docs part of the dictionary.

```
data = response.json()['docs']
```

Output:

```
[{'price': 58.09,
  'high': 58.46,
  'low': 54.7,
  'open': 55.03,
  'volume': 6435500,
  'close': 54.55,
  'bid': 58.09,
  'ask': 58.11,
  'change': 3.54,
  'pctChange': 6.49,
  'date': '20200717170900'},
```

Now we can see the price is nested in an list.

```
data = response.json()['docs'][0]['price']
```

### Output

```
58.09
```

With a bit of work, you can get the data quite efficiently.

Comment: I edited the post with the code I am using,I use your method and the output still "[]"

Comment: Could you provide us the whole code you're using ? I see no URL for example. My answer was based on assumption of what should happen. The page may not be able to be parsed by beautifulsoup because of dynamic content.

Comment: The url is "https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/acoes/bvsp-bovespa/wege3-sa", Im trying to get that 58,09

Comment: The span element you're looking after dynamically generated. That is the javascript in the website is generating the data. You will need to be able to dynamically grab this data. On the website you can do this by reverse engineering the HTTP requests.

Comment: How hard is that?

Comment: Just updating my code/text to help you understand. This website does't require too much to do it.

Comment: It works but i dont understand it. How did you got this link? Is it possible to create a function that does that given the link? This website handle all his prices this way so Im trying to get it from all its other sites

Comment: Have you read my answer and gone through the process I described in the images ? TI've been as explicit as I can be to guide through the process. The URL comes from the request to the server which you can grab through looking through network tools, see the images to go through that process. The URL is the same for all stock prices, there's only one server the website is using to get that data. You will also need the specific parameters for other stock prices to make that type of request. You have to be a lot more specific in your question, as the initial one was about a simple CSS selector.

Comment: I also encourage you to work some of this out yourself. This is part of learning instead of me spoon feeding you all the information. If you make an attempt then I'm happy to help.

Comment: So it is just coincidence that the one I am looking for is the first one in that array?

Comment: It appears to be that the first list item is the most update price for the stock and seems to be what will always be the most update price of the stock.

Comment: How can I know from where "response.json()['docs'][1]" comes from? In which website is it used?

Comment: I've been pretty explicit where it comes from if you read carefully my answer. I've included every single output to build up that expression. response.json() turns the JSON object response into a python dictionary. If you look at the output you can see the key 'docs' has the data you need. so response.json()['docs'], and in the docs value's its the first value you need. hence response.json()['docs'][0].The website its used in is economia.uol.com.br. The url we do a request.get on is different but the the economia.uol.com.br is using the url to get the data it needs to display it on the page

Comment: I know that, but how to know if the third comes from, for example: "https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/acoes/bvsp-bovespa/geti3-sa" or "https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/acoes/bvsp-bovespa/petr4-sa"?

Comment: Because it's usually structured JSON data. To me the JSON data looks incredibly well structured so there's no reason it wouldn't be the same. But I suggest you go through chrome dev tools and network tab to see how it gets the data yourself. I have given a detailed answer on how to do this, including images. Try and apply what I've told you already and find out for yourself, or apply the same code to those urls and see if you get a similar response. I suggest you do the first thing though because you'll learn more.

Comment: I did and i got this: https://api.cotacoes.uol.com/asset/intraday/list/?format=JSON&fields=price,high,low,open,volume,close,bid,ask,change,pctChange,date&item=704&

Comment: Which is the same url i've used in the code example if you look. I'm not really sure what you're confused about. The website you provided uses this api url to get the data and displays stock price etc...  on the page. So every stock on that website is accessing the API to get data.

Comment: Each of this values(1 to 403) has the price that is sent to a website, Is it possible to know which one of the websites is getting a given value?